# Get user documents folder from service working from SYSTEM on Windows. C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am creating a service for Windows by winApi c++.
The Service start to work by SYSTEM user. How can i get the CURRENT user documents folder?

I know the method

```
TCHAR DocumentsPath[MAX_PATH];
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(NULL, DocumentsPath, CSIDL_PERSONAL, TRUE);
```

but, it return other folder, because service work form SYSTEM.

Any solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "CURRENT user"? Remember that multiple users can actually be logged in. Do you mean the currently *active* logged in user? Have you tried searching for how to find out that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "current" user?

Comment: yes, i mean about user working on desktop (active logged).

Comment: user can be switched, after you get active console session id, another user can become active. however you can get current active user token by `WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(),)` and then use this token in `SHGetFolderPath`

Comment: so formally you can use next code - `ULONG SessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
  if (SessionId != MAXDWORD)
  {
   HANDLE hToken;
   if (WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId, &hToken))
   {
    WCHAR DocumentsPath[MAX_PATH];
    SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_PERSONAL, hToken, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, DocumentsPath);
    CloseHandle(hToken);
   }
  }` but on which event you want execute it ? if you say handle some user request - you need get token of user, which do this request

Comment: Almost certainly you don't want to do what you think you do

Answer (score 2):

Thank you RbMm.

It works fine:

```
    ULONG SessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(); 
    if (SessionId != MAXDWORD) 
    { 
         HANDLE hToken; 
         if(WTSQueryUserToken(SessionId, &hToken)) 
         { 
             WCHAR DocumentsPath[MAX_PATH]; 
             SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_PERSONAL, hToken, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, DocumentsPath); 
             CloseHandle(hToken); 
         } 
    }
```

Comment: Does the program support XP? If not, use call [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188) instead of  deprecated `SHGetFolderPath`.